# event for portlets in different page doesnt reload view.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

I have two portlets and am trying to send a event from say portletA to portletB. Now the problem is that when i keep both the portles in same page, it works but when i keep them in different pages, the view.jsp page of PortletB doesnt refresh even though control comes to the the method ProcessAction of portletB(values i am priting gets printed so i guess control comes to that part).

Portlet A
view.jsp

```
<portlet:actionURL var="changedb" name="processEvent"/>


<aui:form method="post" action="<%=changedb.toString() %>">
<aui:fieldset>
    <aui:select label="Select Bot" id="options" name="botname" 
required="true" showEmptyOption="true">
        <aui:option value="otion1" name="option1" 
>option1</aui:option>
        <aui:option value="option2" name="option2" 
>option2</aui:option>
    </aui:select>
<aui:button type="submit" value="Send"/>
</aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>
```

Java method :

```
@ProcessAction(name="processEvent")
public void process(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
    String bot = ParamUtil.getString(request, "botname","");
    String url = "somehttplink" + bot;
    System.out.print("control came inside changedbportlet");
    System.out.println(url);
    QName qName = new QName("botchange");
    response.setEvent(qName, url);

}
```

Portlet B(receiver)

```
<portlet:defineObjects />

<%
String url = (String) renderRequest.getParameter("url");
%> 
<main class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="initial-screen">
 <iframe class="iframe" src="<%= url %>"  width = "1000" height="800" 
></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
```

Java method :

```
@ProcessEvent(qname = "botchange")
public void myEvent(EventRequest request, EventResponse response)
        throws javax.portlet.PortletException,
    java.io.IOException {
    Event event = request.getEvent();
    String url = (String) event.getValue();
    System.out.println("control came to showpageportlet");
    System.out.print(url);
    response.setRenderParameter("url", url);
}
```

i am using Liferay 7 and osgi modules.I have also added below command in the portlet-ext.properties file as per the instructions in https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/portlet+to+portlet+communication.

```
portlet.event.distribution=layout-set
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you have it on the same page it works because the PortletA triggers a render of all portlets on the page. If you have the PortletB somewhere else only the even method gets triggered. What are you trying to archive?

Comment: I am trying to change the iframe url based on a filter and want both portlets to be on different page.

Comment: Should the change of PortletA directly send you to PortletB or you just want to do the state change and then when the user will come to the PortletB he will ses the different URL?

Comment: no it should not redirect to the other portlet.it should make the changes and then when the user goes to that portlet, he should see the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scenario where PortletA sends an information to PortletB that needs to change its state but it is not on the current page you need to have a way how to remember this fact.

The event just transmits the information but the ProtletB is responsible for remembering it.

You could use a session attribute where you store the value or even better a portlet preference that will be edited in the event handler method and read in the render (doView) method. Don't forget to have a default.

you can store the value in the event with this.

```
PortletPreferences preferences = request.getPreferences();
preferences.setValue("url", url);
preferences.store();
```

And then access it wia this.

```
request.getPreferences();
String state = (String) preferences.getValue("url", "")
```

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong there are few concerns i have regarding using the the data in session. What i could read  is that it should be the last option as you can store only few bytes in it and i guess liferay 7 also limits the number of session.and secondly since i am quite new to liferay, so can you please elaborate a bit about the option that you told would be better.

Comment: Yes, the session should be used carefully. It depends on the character of the data that you are storing and the number of users you expecting, the type of users (logged in or not)... I added a reference how to use portal preferences.

Comment: will this method work when the  portlets are present on different pages?. I was trying this but dont know why unable to get the data which i set in the processevent in the doview method .

Comment: should work. I tested it and it worked have a look here https://github.com/mir333/poc-lfr-workspace

Comment: thanks a lot man..it worked..like i said kind of new to liferay. so i was setting the portlet preference in the event of portletA and not receiving it in processevent of portletB.This is why it was not working.

Comment: Just one more thing to ask. this i tried and is you know it is not user specific. you change it for one user and it changes for others as well.So is there any way we can accommodate that in this method itself such that if you change it for one user, it should not change the state for other users as well.

Comment: you would need to store it in user context somewhere. You could prefix the preference with userId or you can create a custom attribute (expando attribute) for the user to store it or you can create a service to store it with service builder. (the options are ordered by complexity and capacity)